# How to enable ssh protocol in libcurl

Tags: curl, ssh, libcurl

I am trying to use Lando init and keep running into this error "curl: (1) Protocol "ssh" not supported or disabled in libcurl" How do I enable the ssh protocol so I can get this to work?

Comment: When i run curl --version I have these protocols : Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp

Comment: did you find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

libcurl doesn't support ssh. It does however support SCP and SFTP (that are done "over" SSH).

Answer (score 0):

When I added my user to the group "docker" it removed this error.

I did the following:

- sudo groupadd docker
- sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

(took me 5 hours to find this).

it also solved the error:
WARN ==> docker is not running!

(windows 11 pro, WSL w/ Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it turned out to be a problem with the office network, rather than an issue with lando or pantheon.
I ended up tethering on my personal phone to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From Curl 7.74, libssh version is supported in curl.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).